# Not able to access set of collections from library using Zotero API

Tags: api

I am not able to access set of zotero's account collections through API.It's showing "not found page".
I am using API like:-

"https://api.zotero.org/usres/{user-id}/collections"

{user-id}:- my account user id

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

If you actually use `usres` instead of `users` in the request that'd be the simplest explanation. Otherwise -- is this a public library? If not, you'll need an API key, though you'd get "Forbidden" as a return.

Also, make sure that you have the right userid -- it should be a number, 4-7 digits.